# User Account Types, Account security

Tags: security, accounts

I new to the world of GNU/Linux account management. I have been told to set up a system for account security would someone please be able to set me on the right track?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi this is quite long and I am sure other members of the community will aid to it but I hope it gives you a good starting point.

**Account Security**

The easiest way to attack a system is to attack it from the inside. Once an account has been compromise the most common attack is a privilege escalation attack, this is where elevated access is gained allowing a user to access resources which would normally be blocked to them, a common way for this to occur is where a bug in a piece of software or an incorrect configuration is exploited. The best way to minimise this risk is to keep unwanted users out of a system and secure the accounts, to only allow an account to perform the required tasks needed for that account role. The first step in securing an account is to set the authentication models using Pluggable Authentication Modules (PAM).

**PAM**

Pluggable Authentication Modules (PAM) is a centralised authentication system used on the Linux system. PAM allow application to offload the authentication to PAM instead of the files where the information is held. PAM authentication files are found in `/etc/pam.d/` each PAM aware configuration file is found in the `pam.d` directory e.g. the ssh pam directive is located `/etc/pam.d/sshd`. The configuration contains a series of directives in the format of: `module_interface control_flag module_name module_args`. PAM uses four different types of module interfaces, each module interface handles a different part of the authentication process, the:

- `auth` module interface authenticate users in the most basic process it checks the validity of a password.
- `Account` module verifies access permissions and if access is permitted (e.g. password expired, locked, account login time).
- `Password` module changes a user’s password.
- `Session` module handles the user’s sessions and handle tasks such as
  mounting a user’s home directory.

A module can use multiple interfaces. All PAM module return either a success or failure as a result. The control flags for a PAM module determine how vital the success or failure is to the overall goal of authenticating the user to the service. The flags are as follows:

- `required` flag mean the module must be successful to continue. If
  the module fails, the user isn’t informed until all tests on that
  interface are complete.
- `requisite` flag is similar to required however no other modules are invoked and the user is informed if they fail this check straight away.
- `sufficient` if this succeeds and no required modules fail then the user is authenticated and no other checks occur otherwise it continues.
- `optional` flag is ignored unless it is the only module reference the
  interface.
- `include` flag includes configuration from another file.

These are simple control flags and there are many complex control flags which uses attribute equal value control pairs, a comprehensive list is in the pam.d man pages.

**Account Types**

There are three main types of accounts: root, service/system and user. The root account can do anything e.g. un/install software or packages, alter configuration, etc. root will always have a User ID (UID) of 0. Account names are not used by the system instead the UID is used, the account names are just for humans. Technically all accounts with a UID above 0 are normal accounts however for management UID in the range of 0 to 1000 are for service accounts and is configurable in `/etc/login.defs`. To create a service accounts, you add the `–r` flag, `useradd –r system_account_name`, otherwise it will have a UID above 1000. The Linux system doesn’t differentiate between accounts with UID above and below one thounds, but it does when the UID is equal to zero because zero is for the root user, the UID is intended to be used by humans to see if it is meant to be used by a human or a service or application.

**Controlling Accounts**

To check that only one user has a UID of zero run the command `awk –F: ‘($3 == “0”) {print}’ /etc/passwd’`
To lock an account run the command `passwd –l account_name`
To unlock an account run the command `passwd –u account_name`
To stop an account being logged into you can simple set their shell parameter in `/etc/passwd` to `/sbin/nologin` to stop them from having a shell thus from having any interactive access. It is better to do this via the command instead of editing the file. The command is `chsh –s SHELL account_name e.g. chsh –s /sbin/nolong /john`
To stop all users logging into a system you can take advantage of the `pam_nologin` module file located in `/etc/nologin` or `/var/run/noloing` if this file exists then logins will be denied and the content will be displayed to the user. Remove the file and people will be able to log back in.
You should also have different accounts for service e.g. a web service should run on its own account and not a user’s account

**Password Security**

Falling to enforce strong password policy may result in the user using weak passwords such as password123, weak password is very vulnerable to brute force attacks. To enforce strong password, use the `pam_pwquality`. You would use this PAM module as part of a directive in a pam configuration file located at `/etc/security/pwquality.conf` and have the PAM usage of `password requisite pam_pwquality.so.`

Passwords where originally stored in `/etc/passwd` in an encrypted or hashed format. The file is a colon separated and contains the username, hashed password, UID, User Group ID number (GID), Full Name, User home directory, the login shell. Almost every application uses this file to convert UID into usernames however, it also means that anything can see the encrypted password which make them vulnerable to dictionary or brute for attacks as they can be copied to another system and cracked. If the password field shows an x it means that the passwords are stored in the `/etc/shadow` file. Storing the password in a separate file mean that this shadow file is only readable to the root user, thus minimising the risk of the passwords being compromised. To convert a system which isn’t using shadow passwords then you need to run the command `pwconv` but if you need to disable shadow passwords then run `pwunconv` as root. The `/etc/shadow` file again contains colon delimited fields; username, hashed password, days since epoch of last password change, days until next password change is allowed, days before a password change is required, days before password expiry notification, days before the account becomes inactive, days since epoch when account expires, reserved for future use. These additional fields in `/etc/shadow` allow for greater control over the accounts on the Linux system. By running the command `chage –l account_name` will show the account aging info. `chage –M MAX_DAYS` will set the maximum number of days during which a password is valid if you attach an account name to the end of that command then it will set it just for that account and not system wide. `chage –E EXPIRE_DATE account_name` command will set a date for when the user account will no longer be accessible the date should be in YYYY-MM-DD format, to unlock or set an account not to expire set the expire flag to negative 1.  To force a password change run the command chage –d 0 account_name. For a complete list check the man page for chage.

To set the defaults edit the file `/etc/login.defs` this is where all the defaults such as the minimal length, maximum age for a password, the minimum age for a password, the password warning before password expires, etc. 
To stop users reusing their previous passwords use the password interface for the pam_pwhistory module by defaults it stores the last ten passwords for a user account in the `/etc/securityopassword`. To change the number of password remember change the remember variable and set it equal to the number of passwords as an argument in the pam_pwhistory module.